# DynamoDB: Is setting ReturnValues to "ALL_NEW" a good practice while updating?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have my database setup with DynamoDB. I want to update an item in a table and return the new values because the callback does some processing based on the new data. So, is it efficient to request for the new data in **ReturnValues**? Is this a good practice or is there something better I can do?

Answer (score 8):

My bad! I should have read the API reference closely. I quote from the [ReturnValues section of UpdateItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#API_UpdateItem_ReturnValues)

> There is no additional cost associated with requesting a return value aside from the small network and processing overhead of receiving a larger response. No Read Capacity Units are consumed.

That answers my question. Let's hope this answers somebody's similar question in the future.